# Lua C API stack visualizer/viewer in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, lua

I wanted to know whether there is someway to trace the Lua stack when debugging C++ applications that use Lua C API from within Visual Studio 2013.

I tried Googling but found nothing other than some stack dump functions. This can be an option for me but a GUI visualizer/viewer similar to the facilities provided for debugging C++ code (Locals, Memory, and Watch windows for example) will be much much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is relatively easy to write your own visualizers.

I implemented one for a custom type with the help of the following link and some more googling:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Writing-graphical-debugger-a17e3d75

Just download the sample and modify it as needed.

(this could have been just a comment but i need 50 reputation for that)